# KDB+ Merging multiple update statements

Tags: kdb

````
q)d:([] f1:`a`b` ;f2:```c; m1:`x``z;m2:``y`z)

f1 f2 m1 m2
-----------
a     x    
b        y 
   c  z  z
````

I want to update the `f1` & `m1` columns to `f2` & `m2` respectively if `f1` & `m1` have `nulls`;  actually I want to merge these 2 queries to one update statement :

```
update f1:f2 from d where null f1
update m1:m2 from d where null m1`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Triadic vector conditional evaluation* [`?`](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/10_Execution_Control/#1013-vector-conditional-evaluation)

```
?[vb;exprtrue;exprfalse]
```

The new query would be :

```
q)update f1:?[null f1;f2;f1] , m1:?[null m1;m2;m1] from d
f1 f2 m1 m2
-----------
a     x    
b     y  y 
c  c  z  z
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative you might like to consider is [fill](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#fill), `^` which allows you to fill nulls in one list with items from another list (in this case, the lists are columns in the table) e.g.

````
q)d:([] f1:`a`b` ;f2:```c; m1:`x``z;m2:``y`z)
q)update f2^f1,m2^m1 from d
f1 f2 m1 m2
-----------
a     x
b     y  y
c  c  z  z
````

Comment: Good one Jon. Small correction -  'update f2^f1,m2^m1 from d'

Answer (score 0):

Fill can be used to update nulls:
If you want to update table d in place, then you can use:
`update f2^f1,m2^m1 from``d
or

```
![`d;();0b;`f1`m1!((^;`f2;`f1);(^;`m2;`m1))]
```

If you want to display the output of update without updating original table, then:
`update f2^f1,m2^m1 from d` or

```
![d;();0b;`f1`m1!((^;`f2;`f1);(^;`m2;`m1))]
```